# Cannot locate by CssSelector in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

I use the :contains() method but I get the error below:

Test Name:  TheMahler3Test
Test FullName:  TestingCssSelector.Mahler3.TheMahler3Test
Test Source:    c:\Users\amahallati\Desktop\TestContainsSelector\TestingCssSelector\Mahler3.cs : line 50
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:05.135

Result Message: System.InvalidOperationException : An invalid or illegal string was specified
Result StackTrace:
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.PropagateExceptionIfNotIgnored(Exception e)
at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
at TestingCssSelector.Mahler3.TheMahler3Test() in c:\Users\amahallati\Desktop\TestContainsSelector\TestingCssSelector\Mahler3.cs:line 59

This is the page's source code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="myDiv">
            <select name="mySelectInput">
                <option value="">Select one...</option>
                <option value="1">AT&T</option>
                <option value="2">TMobile</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the WebDriver C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;


namespace TestingCssSelector
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Mahler3
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://localhost:49638/";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheMahler3Test()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL + "/");
             WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));
            wait.Until(d =>
            {
                return driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/select"));
            });
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div/select")).Click();

            wait.Until(d =>
            {
                return driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option:contains('AT&T')"));
            });
            driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option:contains('AT&T')")).Click();

            // ERROR: Caught exception [ReferenceError: selectLocator is not defined]
        }
        private bool IsElementPresent(By by)
        {
            try
            {
                driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoSuchElementException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private bool IsAlertPresent()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                return true;
            }
            catch (NoAlertPresentException)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        private string CloseAlertAndGetItsText()
        {
            try
            {
                IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
                string alertText = alert.Text;
                if (acceptNextAlert)
                {
                    alert.Accept();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.Dismiss();
                }
                return alertText;
            }
            finally
            {
                acceptNextAlert = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you can add jquery to the page you could use Browser.ScriptQuery<IWebElement>("return $('select').get(0);")  if your using https://github.com/leblancmeneses/RobustHaven.IntegrationTests    this approach will let you use jquery chained expression to grab IWebElement or a collection of IWebElement. (includes using find, filter, chaining)

Answer (score 0):

`contains` is not part of the CSS selector specification and is therefore not going to work.

The `contains` selector we all know and love comes from [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), the CSS-selector engine behind [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Unless you wish to physically load Sizzle or jQuery into your page, then you are not going to be able to use your current solution.

The only real way of doing text-based searching is using XPath, or find a list of elements (using anyway you like) and filtering them *within code*.

For your basic page, it's easy enough to simply select it by ID, so simply:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.FindElement(By.Id("mySelectInput")));
```

You would then select it by using:

```
select.SelectByVisibleText("AT&T");
```